# Differences to earlier instance within group or external variable

Tags: r, data.table

I have data

```
dat1 <- data.table(id=1:9,
                   group=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                   t=c(14,17,20,21,26,89,90,95,99),
                   index=c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4)
                  )
```

and I would like to compute the difference on `t` to the previous value, according to `index`. For the first instance of each group, I would like to compute the difference to some external variable

```
dat2 <- data.table(group=c(1,2,3),
                   start=c(10,15,80)
                  )
```

such that the following result should be obtained:

```
> res 
   id group  t index dif
1:  1     1 14     1   4
2:  2     1 17     2   3
3:  3     2 20     1   5
4:  4     2 21     2   1
5:  5     2 26     3   5
6:  6     3 89     1   9
7:  7     3 90     2   1
8:  8     3 95     3   5
9:  9     3 99     4   4
```

I have tried using

```
dat1[ , ifelse(index == min(index), dif := t - dat2$start, dif := t - t[-1]), by = group]
```

but I was unsure about referencing other elements of the same group and external elements in one step. Is this at all possible using data.table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
dat1[, dif := ifelse(index == min(index),
                     t - dat2$start[match(.BY, dat2$group)],
                     t - shift(t))
     , by = group][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    id group  t index dif
> 1:  1     1 14     1   4
> 2:  2     1 17     2   3
> 3:  3     2 20     1   5
> 4:  4     2 21     2   1
> 5:  5     2 26     3   5
> 6:  6     3 89     1   9
> 7:  7     3 90     2   1
> 8:  8     3 95     3   5
> 9:  9     3 99     4   4
> ```

Or a variant as proposed by @jogo in the comments which avoids the ifelse:

```
dat1[, dif := t - shift(t), by = group
     ][index == 1, dif := t - dat2[group==.BY, start], by = group][]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would try to avoid `ifelse` and use data.tables efficient join-capabilities:

```
dat1[dat2, on = "group",                                # join on group
          start := i.start][,                           # add start value
          diff  := diff(c(start[1L], t)), by = group][, # compute difference
          start := NULL]                                # remove start value
```

The resulting table is:

```
#   id group  t index diff
#1:  1     1 14     1    4
#2:  2     1 17     2    3
#3:  3     2 20     1    5
#4:  4     2 21     2    1
#5:  5     2 26     3    5
#6:  6     3 89     1    9
#7:  7     3 90     2    1
#8:  8     3 95     3    5
#9:  9     3 99     4    4
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `shift` with a dynamic `fill` argument: Index 'dat2' with `.BY` to get 'start' values for each 'group':

```
dat1[ , dif := t - shift(t, fill = dat2[group == .BY, start]), by = group]

#    id group  t index dif
# 1:  1     1 14     1   4
# 2:  2     1 17     2   3
# 3:  3     2 20     1   5
# 4:  4     2 21     2   1
# 5:  5     2 26     3   5
# 6:  6     3 89     1   9
# 7:  7     3 90     2   1
# 8:  8     3 95     3   5
# 9:  9     3 99     4   4
```

---

Alternatively, you can do this in steps. Probably a matter of taste, but I find it more transparent than the `ifelse` way.

First the 'normal' `shift`. Then add an 'index' variable to 'dat2' and do an update join.

```
dat1[ , dif := t - shift(t), by = group]

dat2[ , index := 1]
dat1[dat2, on = .(group, index), dif := t - start]
```